# jQuery Mobile nested list refresh solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, browser-history, pushstate

I am trying to find a workaround for refreshing nested lists with version 1.1 of jquery Mobile which currently leaves you with a blank page.

I know one existing solution is to enable pushState but that sends you back to the root of the list and screws with the history state on your next nested list view.

**The solution I came up** with below is not pretty but works on iOS and newer android.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){

 var urlEx = '#&ui-page=5-0';  //ending of nested list url

 if (window.location.href.indexOf(urlEx) != -1){

  history.replaceState("", "0", "index.php");
   setTimeout("window.location.href='https://FULLURL#/FULLURL&ui-page=5-0'",100);
 }

 window.history.pushState("", "0", "index.php"); 

});
```

I realize that pushState and replaceState aren't supported by every browser and that I could try to use:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.substring(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#'));
```

instead but it becomes much choppier of a user experience.

I'm hoping someone could shed some light on what could be done better or how it can be done better/more reliably.

Comment: If your worried about reliability why aren't you using a stable version of JQM?

Comment: My mistake. I ment 1.1 Getting ahead of myself :)

Comment: Could you provide HTML code so that we can work on finding possible workarounds?

Comment: I have a feeling that you are doing too much and it could be fixed without touching the state, but I'm not sure if I get your situation right. A link to the (not)working code would be the best. Or post a zip somewhere

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshing" nested lists? Do you mean you load thing dynamically and then you need to re-render the list? Is it just too hard to preload everything?

Comment: If you are adding child elements to the listview then you can call ``.refresh('listview')`` on the object. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083507/how-to-insert-child-elements-into-a-listview

Answer (score 1):

`$("#<mySelector>").listview("refresh");`

or

`$("#<mySelector>").refresh("listview");`

Unless I'm completely mis-understanding your question, you should be able to use either of the lines above to refresh the list that you're adding to where `<mySelector>` is whatever JQuery-compatible selector that will return your listview.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```
$("#newList").append("<li class='ui-li-desc'><div><b>"+data[i].Title+":</b></div><small><div class='ui- li-desc'>"+data[i].Content+"</div></small></li>");

$("#newList").listview("refresh");
```

Here `#newlist` is the ID for ul and data is an object.